# How to check which version of Python a Django site is using?

Tags: python, django, apache

I can't believe this hasn't been asking on here before. Besides using a syntax error to make the debug screen appear in the browser, is there another way to check which version of Python a Django site is running?

Comment: In what way? Are you hosting the site?

Comment: Yes, I have it on a linux box. I have Python 2.6.6 and Python 2.7.9 installed and just want to confirm it's using the Python in my virtual env as last time it was not.

Comment: You could install the Django debug toolbar which displays the Python version in use.

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.version)` will work for just about any version, including the two you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Not that different from checking Python version from any Python program, https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.python_version

```
>>> from platform import python_version
>>> python_version()     # Read this value from e.g. a Django command, or a page 
'2.7.6'

# Or
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info   
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Comment: So you're suggesting to put it into my code temporarily?